# Why does this reduce function only work when the last argument is specified?

Tags: javascript

The reduce method is still confusing to me. 
Why does

```
const sumOfCubes = nums => nums.reduce((a,b) => a + Math.pow(b, 3))
```

not work, but

```
const sumOfCubes = nums => nums.reduce((a,b) => a + Math.pow(b, 3), 0)
```

does?

Comment: If you don't supply the initial parameter, then `a` would be the *first* element from the array. Which means that with `[2, 3, 4]` the first operation will be `2 + Math.pow(3, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because with `reduce` you should declare what the start/default value of the accumulator is. Which you are doing in the second example with passing `0` as an argument.

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

As suggested by @VLAZ, if you do not declare it will use the first element of the array and skip it:

> InitialValue Optional
>   A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used and skipped. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initialValue will throw a TypeError.

Comment: "*you need to declare what the start/default value of the accumulator is*" you don't **need** to do it. If you don't, then you'd get the first element of the array as the initial value. This *can* work but not always.

Answer (score 1):

With only one argument, `array.reduce(fn)` is mostly the same as

```
for (let i = 1, a = array[0]; i < array.length; ++i)
  a = fn(a, array[i]);
```

Thus in your case the first value, 2, is never cubed, so you get the wrong sum.

*With* the second argument, it's like:

```
for (let i = 0, a = secondParameter; i < array.length; ++i)
  a = fn(a, array[i]);
```

Thus on the first iteration, the value to add is correctly 0 when you pass that as the second parameter, and each value in the array will be cubed.